# How to run a function in a singleton file only when electron main process is ready

Tags: vue.js, electron

I am using electron + vue, in my vue files, there is a file called globals.ts which is a file that exports global variables for all my vue files to use, it is a singleton file, I am trying to get it to communicate with electrons main process to fetch the user's machine IP address, however, there are errors occuring because apparently the main process is not finished loading before globals.ts function runs, meaning the ipcRenderer function is invoked before the main has the API available. How do i get it to wait for the main process to finish loading first so i can safely invoke a function and get a result?

```
//electron/main/main.ts
async function createWindow() {//...code to create window here}
    
ipcMain.handle("getMachineIPv4", (e, arg) => {
  console.log("getting ipv4");
  const interfaces = os.networkInterfaces();
  for (const interfaceName in interfaces) {
    const interfaceInfo = interfaces[interfaceName];
    for (const info of interfaceInfo) {
      if (info.family === "IPv4" && !info.internal) {
        return info.address;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

.

```
//electron/preload/preload.ts
    contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("ipcRenderer", {
  send: (channel: string, data: string) => {
    // whitelist channels
    let validChannels = ["OpenFolder"];
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
    }
  },
  receive: (channel, func) => {
    let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
      ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args));
    }
  },
  invoke: (channel, arg) => {
    //invoke is an async function with a promise
    console.log(channel + " invoked");
    let validChannels = ["asyncFunc", "getMachineIPv4"];
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
      return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, arg);
    }
  },
});
```

.

```
//inside src folder /assets/globals.ts

 export const address: Promise<string> = (async () => {
  try {
    const hostname: string = await window.ipcRenderer.invoke("getMachineIPv4", "please work");
    const firstThreeNumbers = hostname.split(".")[0];
    const portNumber = "3000";
    const subnet = "10";
    if (firstThreeNumbers === "123") {
      return `123.123.1111.${subnet}:${portNumber}`;
    } else if (firstThreeNumbers === "101") {
      return `123.123.111.${subnet}:${portNumber}`;
    } else if (hostname == "localhost") {
      // Default, usually localhost
      return `123.123.111.${subnet}:${portNumber}`;
    } else {
      console.error("ip address not found");
      return "error";
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to get address:", error);
    return "error";
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `const address` in your `globals.ts` is an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), which means it will get executed as soon as the `globals.ts` file is imported. The way to solve this, is to remove the invocation (the `();`) at the very end of the declaration of `address` to turn the variable into a function.

This will not make it possible for the variable itself to be a singleton, but you can get around that by using a non-exported variable in the file to store the value once it has been retrieved and re-use that when the function is called again. That could look somewhat like this:

```
const address: string | undefined = undefined;

export const getAddress = async (): Promise<string> => {
  if (address) {
    return address;
  }

  try {
    const hostname: string = await window.ipcRenderer.invoke("getMachineIPv4", "works now");
    const firstThreeNumbers = hostname.split(".")[0];
    const portNumber = "3000";
    const subnet = "10";

    if (firstThreeNumbers === "123") {
      address = `123.123.1111.${subnet}:${portNumber}`;
    } else if (firstThreeNumbers === "101") {
      address = `123.123.111.${subnet}:${portNumber}`;
    } else if (hostname == "localhost") {
      // Default, usually localhost
      address = `123.123.111.${subnet}:${portNumber}`;
    } else {
      console.error("ip address not found");
      return "error";
    }

    return address;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to get address:", error);
    return "error";
  }
};
```

You can then call that function to obtain the address instead of reading it from the variable. When you call the function from the renderer, which can only be started after `app.on("ready")`, it is guaranteed that your main process will be initialized.

```
import { getAddress } from "./<path>/<to>/globals.ts";


async function doAddressStuff() {
  const address = await getAddress();

  // more address stuff ...
}
```

I hope that helps, if anything is unclear, let me know!